# jQuery executing script multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm doing a little project and got a small problem. I'm printing out a table from MySQL database data.

One of the fields is image. I print it out and I want it to pop up when clicked but all I can do is execute the script only once, meaning only the first picture on the page will pop up when clicked.

```
<div id="contentRight">

    .......

    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top">
        <?php do { ?>
            <table width="630" border="1" class="TableStyle">
              <tr>
    ........
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#img').on('click','.btn', function ()  {
              var image = '<img src="<?php echo $row_ManageUsers['preview_thumb']; ?>">';
              $('#popover').popover({placement: 'bottom', content: image, html: true});
           });
        });
        </script>
                <td width="100" height="100" rowspan="3" id="img"><a id="popover" class="btn" rel="popover" data-content="" title="Preview" >
                <img src="<?php echo $row_ManageUsers['preview_thumb']; ?>" width="130px" height="130px" class="img-thumbnail" $nbsp;></a>
              </td>
              </tr>

    .......
          <?php } while ($row_ManageUsers = mysql_fetch_assoc($ManageUsers)); ?> 
    .......
```

The script is copied and it gets a proper value every time but it will not execute.

Any advice?

Comment: Is your jQuery being repeatedly output in a PHP loop??

Comment: why are you putting a selector '.btn', in the event listener?

Comment: You are using ID's, change #img and #popover to classes.

Comment: @j08691 Yes, that was the intention, or at least how I imagined it would work

Comment: @Joerg Doing makes the images not display on the page at all

Comment: @satchcoder At the point of writing that it was mostly experimenting with whatever I could come up with, so I left it at that

Comment: If you're repeatedly outputting a click event handler you're going to execute your code for as many times you you loop. 10 click handlers = 10 functions being run. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hds1nw15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're outputting `<td id="img">` for every `<td>`, that is your issue. IDs need to be unique, so jQuery only finds the first instance of `#img` when the click happens.

Change `id="img"` to `class="img"` and change this:

```
$('#img').on('click','.btn', function ()...
```

to this:

```
$('.img').on('click','.btn', function ()...
```

That should do the trick.

Also, here is info regarding IDs and the HTML5 spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain
>   any space characters.

Comment: No results with the classes. I get even less response from the thing

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Also, you may want to take a look at @Joerg 's answer below. He gives a couple of good tips on how to organize your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give your code a little bit more structure and separate the HTMl and the JS part.

Output your table rows  by looping or what ever AND remove the ID's and use CLASSES. ID's have to be unique in the document. Also remove width and heigth and do that in CSS. Your row should look something like that:

```
<tr>
   <td rowspan="3">
      <a class="btn" rel="popover" title="Preview" >
         <img src="<?php echo $row_ManageUsers['preview_thumb']; ?> />"
      </a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Test the above code, you should see the images. Next step is to write the jQuery part.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.btn').on('click', function (){
         var image = '<img src="' + $(this + ' img').attr('src') + '" />';
         $(this).popover({
            placement: 'bottom',
            content: image,
            html: true
         });
      });
   });
</script>
```

This part you put in the HEAD of your HTML after the part, where you are loading jQuery.

I have not tested the code.

TIPP: If you are unsure with solving a problem, then cut it into small pieces, write the code and test is. In the end put all the small parts together.